# How does Unix/shell scripting work?

Tags: shell, unix, scripting

I was just curious about the logic of a Unix environment. I'm under the impression that Unix is an operating system, but also a shell. As a subset there are more specific shells such as  Bourne, Bash, and Korn shells. And these shells are interpreters and have their own functions to interpret scripts, and also have functions such as ping, pwd, etc? So there are shells within shells? Is everything I said correct?

Answer (score 1):

The Unix operating system is *not* a shell.

A shell is just a program that makes it easy to interact with your computer by running programs and manipulating data streams.

The 'functions' you mentioned are programs, and not part of the shell.

You can run a shell from another shell if you want.  For example, you are in a bash session and you want to switch to csh for something.  You run `csh` and when you're finished, you `exit` to return to the bash shell.

If you like, you can run another copy of bash inside a bash session.  You might do this if you want to modify some environment variables and then undo your changes when you return.

In all these cases, all you did was run a program from a shell and waited for it to terminate.  If that program also happened to be a shell, it's nothing special.

Comment: Right, thank you. So all programs like that are built onto Unix? Does each shell not have any language syntax if its own?

Comment: Shells have some basic syntax in common, otherwise everyone would get confused.  But their language features and syntax differs.  They are basic interpreters, after all.  For example, `csh` uses C-style syntax.

Comment: +1 for a good answer though why you'd want to run csh from bash is beyond me :-)